# Parity Ethereum on Windows : Corruption block checksum mismatch - fails to launch

Tags: wallets, parity

I have installed Parity Ethereum on my Windows 7 (64 bits) laptop. It has worked fine for some weeks. Today, I was forced to hard-reboot my laptop for some reason, while Parity wallet was running. Due to the hard-boot, there was an auto-run of ChkDsk at restart that did some clean-up. I'm trying to relaunch Parity Ethereum, it attempts to launch & I see Parity icon in my system-tray. But after a few seconds, the icon disappears & Parity also doesn't show up as a new tab in Chrome browser. On launching Parity via command line, I receive the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to update version: "Corruption: block checksum mismatch"', C:\bot\slave\stable-dist-rustc-win-msvc-64\build\src\libcore\result.rs:868
```

Can anyone please guide me about how to resolve this? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your database is corrupted. Run

```
> parity.exe db kill
```

And then restart parity. This will delete your chain and state and resync, which should take a couple of minutes.